# How to scrape all of the pages on amazon from a search result with python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape all of the pages from a search result on amazon with python. However, the code below only returns the listings on page 1. Can anyone offer some suggestions on how to gather the other pages? Setting a specific range doesn't work?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
import time

def get_url(search_term):
    template = 'https://www.amazon.com/s?k={}'
    search_term = search_term.replace(' ', '+')
    url = template.format(search_term)
    return url

def scrape_records(item):
    atag = item.h2.a
    description = atag.text.strip()
    url = 'https://amazon.com' + atag.get('href')

    price_parent = item.find('span', 'a-price')
    price = price_parent.find('span', 'a-offscreen').text.strip() if price_parent and price_parent.find('span', 'a-offscreen') else ''

    rating_element = item.find('span', {'class': 'a-icon-alt'})
    rating = rating_element.text.strip() if rating_element else ''

    review_count_element = item.find('span', {'class': 'a-size-base', 'dir': 'auto'})
    review_count = review_count_element.text.strip() if review_count_element else ''

    result = (description, price, rating, review_count, url)
    return result

def scrape_amazon(search_term):
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    records = []
    page = 1

    url = get_url(search_term)
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(2)  # Add a short delay to let the page load

    while True:
        # Scroll to the bottom of the page to load more items
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        time.sleep(2)  # Add a short delay to let the page load

        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
        results = soup.find_all('div', {'data-component-type': 's-search-result'})

        for item in results:
            try:
                record = scrape_records(item)
                records.append(record)
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error scraping item: {e}")

        # Check if there is a "Next" button on the page
        pagination_next = []
        for x in soup.find_all('a', {'class': 's-pagination-item' 's-pagination-button'}):
            pagination_next.append(x)
        print(pagination_next)
        if not any(a.get_text() == 'Next' for a in pagination_next):
            break  # Stop scraping if there are no more pages

        page += 1

    driver.close()

    # Process the records
    df = pd.DataFrame(records, columns=['Description', 'Price', 'Rating', 'Review Count', 'URL'])
    return df

# Get user input for the search term
search_term = 'ultrawide monitor'

# Scrape Amazon for the search term
df = scrape_amazon(search_term)

# Export DataFrame to Excel
df.to_excel('output.xlsx', index=False)
```

Please list anyways that I can make this code scrape all of the pages from the search.

Comment: you should be able to just do "&page=2", but you will hit a captcha at some point so you need a way to deal with that.

Comment: won't the script need to know how many pages to be passed in?

Comment: the total is somewhere on the page, or you can just stop when there's no more products

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below, updated Review count locator and changed logic to break out of loop when Next button is not shown otherwise click on next page and scrape Also i have used [undetected-chromedriver](https://pypi.org/project/undetected-chromedriver/2.1.1/) for selenium and passing [fake user agent](https://pypi.org/project/fake-useragent/) to avoid bot detection

```
import undetected_chromedriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ExpectedConditions
import pandas as pd
import time
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

from selenium.common import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait


def get_url(search_term):
    template = 'https://www.amazon.com/s?k={}'
    search_term = search_term.replace(' ', '+')
    url = template.format(search_term)
    return url


def scrape_records(item):
    atag = item.h2.a
    description = atag.text.strip()
    url = 'https://amazon.com' + atag.get('href')

    price_parent = item.find('span', 'a-price')
    price = price_parent.find('span', 'a-offscreen').text.strip() if price_parent and price_parent.find('span',
                                                                                                        'a-offscreen') else ''

    rating_element = item.find('span', {'class': 'a-icon-alt'})
    rating = rating_element.text.strip() if rating_element else ''

    review_count_element = item.find('span', {'class': 'a-size-base s-underline-text'})
    review_count = review_count_element.text.strip() if review_count_element else ''

    result = (description, price, rating, review_count, url)
    return result


def scrape_amazon(search_term):
    ua = UserAgent()
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument(f"user-agent={ua.random}")
    driver = undetected_chromedriver.Chrome(options=options)
    url = get_url(search_term)
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(5)
    records = []
    while True:

        # Scroll to the bottom of the page to load more items
        # Add a short delay to let the page load
        time.sleep(5)
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
        results = soup.find_all('div', {'data-component-type': 's-search-result'})

        for item in results:
            try:
                record = scrape_records(item)
                records.append(record)
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error scraping item: {e}")

        # Check if there is a "Next" button on the page
        try:
            nextButton = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//a[text()="Next"]')
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", nextButton)
            WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.element_to_be_clickable(nextButton))
            nextButton.click()
        except NoSuchElementException:
            print("Breaking as Last page Reached")
            break

    driver.close()

    # Process the records
    df = pd.DataFrame(records, columns=['Description', 'Price', 'Rating', 'Review Count', 'URL'])
    return df


# Get user input for the search term
search_term = 'ultrawide monitor'

# Scrape Amazon for the search term
df = scrape_amazon(search_term)

# Export DataFrame to Excel
df.to_excel('output.xlsx', index=False)
```

outputs
[image]